# C++ class template - constructor for a specific instance

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specify an additional constructor for a specific instance of a templated class?

Please take a look at the example below.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

class float4 {
private:
    __m128 _data;
public:
    explicit float4(const float& val = 0.0f)
        : _data(_mm_set1_ps(val)) {}
    ~float4(void) = default;
};

template<typename DATATYPE>
class Vec3 {
private:
    DATATYPE _data[3];
public:
    explicit Vec3(const DATATYPE& x, const DATATYPE& y, const DATATYPE& z)
        : _data{ x, y, z } {}

    // This wouldn't work because such a constructor is already defined for DATATYPE=float.
    // What I want is to have such a constructor for DATATYPE=float4.
    //explicit Vec3(const float& x, const float& y, const float& z)
    //  : _data{ DATATYPE(x), DATATYPE(y), DATATYPE(z) } {}

    ~Vec3(void) = default;
};

template class Vec3<float>;
template class Vec3<float4>;

typedef Vec3<float>  Vec3f;
typedef Vec3<float4> Vec3f_simd;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const Vec3f      a(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    const Vec3f_simd b(float4(1.0f), float4(2.0f), float4(3.0f)); // OK

    //const Vec3f_simd c(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f); // Not OK
}
```

So we have two 'base' types - `float` and `float4`. I'd like to have a class template `Vec3` to be used with these two base types. Fine so far. What I also want to have is a constructor in `Vec3<float4>` only which would accept `x`, `y`, and `z` as floats and then construct `float4(x)`, `float4(y)`, and `float4(z)` into `Vec3<float4>::_data`. The problem is that the generated `Vec3<float>` wouldn't compile because the two constructors would coincide.

Comment: FWIW if you get rid of the `explicit` from `explicit float4(const float& val = 0.0f)` then `const Vec3f_simd c(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f); ` would just work

Comment: It's weird that you duplicate `float4` 3 times. Aren't you supposed to have only one copy?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I assume you talk about `DATATYPE _data[3];` in the `Vec3<float4>` class? Yes, that's the intention - to have a geometry vector class holding a SoA using SIMD.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, I thought about it, but in general I prefer to avoid such implicit conversions. For the testing, just to see what happens, I now removed `explicit` and was surprised to see that the *copy* constructor of float4 is used (I usually delete them unless I explicitly understand that I need them).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `requires`:

```
explicit Vec3(...) requires std::same_as<DATATYPE, float4>
//                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Pre-C++20 you'd have to make the constructor a template to add SFINAE:

```
template <typename T = DATATYPE, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, float4>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
explicit Vec3(...)
```